# Get first element of array or nothing if array is empty

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection:

```
[
    {"_id": 1, "show": "Show A", "episodes": ["a", "b", "c"]},
    {"_id": 2, "show": "Show B", "episodes": ["first"]},
    {"_id": 3, "show": "Show C", "episodes": []}
]
```

and I need to convert it (by aggregation framework) to:

```
[
    {"_id": 1, "show": "Show A", "firstEpisode": "a"},
    {"_id": 2, "show": "Show B", "firstEpisode": "first"},
    {"_id": 3, "show": "Show C"}
]
```

`$slice` returns array, but I need value.

`$unwind` drops "show C" away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your documents and use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator new in MongoDB 3.2.

```
db.coll.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { 
            "show": 1, 
            "firstEpisode": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$episodes", 0 ] } 
        }}
    ]
)
```

Which produces:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "show" : "Show A", "firstEpisode" : "a" }
{ "_id" : 2, "show" : "Show B", "firstEpisode" : "first" }
{ "_id" : 3, "show" : "Show C" }
```

Now from MongoDB 3.0 backward, you need a different approach.

First you need to assign a default value to "episodes" if the array is *empty* using a logical [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)ition processing and the [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) operator.The condition is [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) which returns true if the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the array is 0.

The [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind) pipeline operator deconstruct the "episodes" array.

The final stage in the pipeline is the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) stage, where your group your documents by `_id` and use the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) accumulator operator to return the "first" element in the array.

```
db.coll.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { 
            "show": 1, 
            "episodes": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ { "$size": "$episodes" }, 0 ] }, 
                    { "$literal": [ null ] }, 
                    "$episodes" 
                ]
            }
        }}, 
       { "$unwind": "$episodes" }, 
       { "$group": { 
           "_id": "$_id",  
           "show": { "$first": "$show" }, 
           "firstEpisode": { "$first": "$episodes" } 
       }}  
    ]
)
```

which yields:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "show" : "Show C", "firstEpisode" : null }
{ "_id" : 2, "show" : "Show B", "firstEpisode" : "first" }
{ "_id" : 1, "show" : "Show A", "firstEpisode" : "a" }
```

Note that it is not possible to exclude the "episodes" field in the documents.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) Array Operator to return the element at the specified array index:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
       { $project: { show: 1, firstEpisode: {$arrayElemAt: ["$episodes", 0] } } } 
])
```

Since if the index exceeds the array bounds, `$arrayElemAt` does not return any result, show `C` wouldn't have any `firstEpisode`.